# Linq Total Based on Location

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following code which does the job of returning a list of records totalling the stock at each location. I am trying to clean up the program before I take it any further. Is there a way to do the same thing with LINQ? I know this is a mess, and I would like to refine it.

Thanks for looking!

```
private static List < Stock_Paper_Record > Get_Final_List(List < Stock_Paper_Record > Finallist, List < Stock_Paper_Record > papr, List < string > Codes, List < string > locs) {
    int ii = 0;
    int totalg = 0;
    int totall = 0;
    int totalp = 0;
    decimal gsm = 0;
    decimal size1 = 0;
    decimal size2 = 0;
    int commited = 0;
    int OnOrder = 0;
    int THRESH = 0;
    int iount = 0;
    papr.Sort((x, y) => String.Compare(x.Code, y.Code));
    Finallist.Sort((x, y) => String.Compare(x.Code, y.Code));
    int ic = 0;
    int it = 0;
    List < string > ls = new List < string > ();
    List < decimal > st = new List < decimal > ();
    foreach(string s in Codes) {
        for (int iii = 0; iii < papr.Count; iii++) {
            if (s == papr[iii].Code && papr[iii].Location == "GLASGOW") {
                totalg += Convert.ToInt32(papr[iii].Stock);
                gsm = papr[iii].Grammage;
                size1 = papr[iii].Size1;
                size2 = papr[iii].Size2;
                commited = papr[iii].Commited;
                OnOrder = papr[iii].Onorderi;
                THRESH = papr[iii].Threshholdi;
            }
            if (s == papr[iii].Code && papr[iii].Location == "LONDON") {
                totall += Convert.ToInt32(papr[iii].Stock);
                gsm = papr[iii].Grammage;
                size1 = papr[iii].Size1;
                size2 = papr[iii].Size2;
                commited = papr[iii].Commited;
                OnOrder = papr[iii].Onorderi;
                THRESH = papr[iii].Threshholdi;
            }
            if (s == papr[iii].Code && papr[iii].Location == "PARIS") {
                totalp += Convert.ToInt32(papr[iii].Stock);
                gsm = papr[iii].Grammage;
                size1 = papr[iii].Size1;
                size2 = papr[iii].Size2;
                commited = papr[iii].Commited;
                OnOrder = papr[iii].Onorderi;
                THRESH = papr[iii].Threshholdi;
            } else {}
        }
        Finallist.Add(new Stock_Paper_Record() {
            Location = "BOTH", Code = Codes[iount], Stocki = totalg + totall + totalp + OnOrder, BBstocki = totalg, Lmstocki = totall, Ingstocki = totalp, Commited = commited, Ballance = (totalg + totall + totalp + OnOrder) - commited, Size1 = size1, Size2 = size2, Grammage = gsm, Threshholdi = THRESH, Onorderi = OnOrder
        });
        totalg = 0;
        totall = 0;
        totalp = 0;
        ii++;
        iount++;
    }
    return Finallist;
}
```

Comment: Thats's a lot of code and not much question. Can you remove the commented out code, reformat it, and say more about what you want to achieve?

Comment: Linq is no universal remedy for dirty code. You should simplify your code as much as possible, restructure it, rename variables. After you´ve done this you may consider using linq.

Comment: fair points, i will edit and repost

Comment: Also consider using http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you just want a review of working code.

Comment: Also could you explain why you are passing a FinalList if you are returning  it from the method (it's a reference type, so the changes are propagated to the caller anyway), and what it contains initially.

Comment: Is commited, OnOrder, size1, size2, THRESH correct?  It seems odd that you aren't summing them before returning.  For each code, you are returning only the latest found.

Comment: I did it partially, but since you are doing so many calculations that are based on other calculations, you can either do it quickly, or you need to do multiple steps and it's just a PITA.  You should really reconsider how you are returning your data, first.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I going to re-design the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be pretty close, however, if you supply a code that there is no records for, this will not return a record for it with all 0's, but your original code did.  Not sure if that matters to you or not.

```
private static List<Stock_Paper_Record> Get_Final_List(List<Stock_Paper_Record> Finallist, List<Stock_Paper_Record> papr, List<string> Codes, List<string> locs) {

    return papr
      .Where(p=>Codes.Contains(p.Location))
      .GroupBy(p=>p.Code)
      .Select(g=>new {
        Code=g.Key,
        BBstocki=g.Where(p=>p.Location=="GLASGOW").Sum(p=>Convert.ToInt32(p.Stock)),
        Lmstocki=g.Where(p=>p.Location=="LONDON").Sum(p=>Convert.ToInt32(p.Stock)),
        Ingstocki=g.Where(p=>p.Location=="PARIS").Sum(p=>Convert.ToInt32(p.Stock)),
        Commited=g.FirstOrDefault().Commited,
        Size1=g.FirstOrDefault().Size1,
        Size2=g.FirstOrDefault().Size2,
        Grammage=g.FirstOrDefault().Grammage,
        Threshholdi=g.FirstOrDefault().Threshholdi,
        Onorderi=g.FirstOrDefault().Onorderi
      }).Select(g=>new Stock_Paper_Record {
        Location="BOTH",
        Code=g.Code,
        BBstocki=g.BBstocki,
        Lmstocki=g.Lmstocki,
        Ingstocki=g.Ingstocki,
        Commited=g.Commited,
        Size1=g.Size1,
        Size2=g.Size2,
        Grammage=g.Grammage,
        Threshholdi=g.Threshholdi,
        Onorderi=g.Onorderi,
        Stocki=g.BBstocki+g.Lmstocki+g.Ingstocki+g.Onorderi,
        Ballance=g.BBstocki+g.Lmstocki+g.Ingstocki+g.Onorderi=g.Commited
      })
      .ToList();
}
```